# change file system F2FS back to EXT4

Tags: file-system

Xiaomi Poco M3 (citrus) A-only (SAR) system-as-root device shipped with MIUI 12 Android 10 and F2FS (FBE encryption). I don't trust F2FS and want to run it plain EXT4 unencrypted. I formatted EXT4 and changed `/vendor/etc/fstab.qcom` inside `super.img` but that doesn't seem to work.

After I change back `fstab.qcom` to F2FS it works again (unencrypted) so this should not an issue with encryption or AVB/dm-verity.

```
$ adb disable-verity
verity is already disabled
$ adb shell avbctl disable-verification
verification is already disabled
$
```

There is no fstab in dtbo `magiskboot` print nothing.

```
$ adb pull /dev/block/platform/soc/4804000.ufshc/by-name/dtbo dtbo.img
$ 7z x Magisk-v21.4.zip
$ x86/magiskboot dtb dtbo.img print -f
Loading dtbs from [dtbo.img]

$
```

How and where can I change the default file system type for userdata?

Comment: note: for some reason there is also fstab.qcom in boot ramdisk (but also with no effect)